# application Icon Badge Number in ios5

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

i was just wondering, if that the applicationIconBadgeNumber have been changed in iso 5 ?

cus when i run my apps in the sim the number works fine, but if run it on my iPhone it´s not showing it ?

i haven't changed my code that was working in iOS 4.3.

```
int a = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = a ;
```

been on google all day .....

Hope you can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely because the "Badge App Icon" setting for your app is not turned on in the new Notification Center.

[screenshot http://www.karthikk.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/turn-off-notifications-ios5-4.png](http://www.karthikk.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/turn-off-notifications-ios5-4.png)

Go to **Settings** > **Notifications**. Find your app either in "In Notification Center" section or "Not In Notification Center" section, and tap on it. Then turn on the "Badge App Icon" setting. p/s: it doesn't matter if you app is not in notification center (i.e. Notification Center = OFF); the badge icon setting does take effect nevertheless.

Comment: Wow. Spent about 30 mins furiously changing code before I found this answer. Do I ever feel stupid! Thanks @Lukman!