# xcode, running app on device cause red stamp to appear

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am not sure why, but every time I run this specific app on a iOS device a red stamp appear with the number 5. Can someone tell me why this is happening? This doesn't happened on the simulator.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the stamp?

Comment: It just like an update red stamp you get on the app store.It appears on the top right corner.

Comment: Top right corner of an icon?

Answer (score 2):

This is used to communicate important information to the user of said app. This is set in your application by supplying an NSInteger to `applicationIconBadgeNumber`. For instance, Apple's App Store uses the overlay to inform a user that an update is available for X number of his/her app's. The Mail App uses it to inform the user that they have unread messages. Some applications add an `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to inform the user that they have received a Push Message.

Read more about it from [Apple Developer Doc's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber)

You can also turn this off for the application if you find it bothersome. Follow instructions in this [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844950/1260593).